# Scraping product category through python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, categories

I want product category alongside with the name of product. I've tried this code but it doesn't work. In my code the list "key" contains all the product categories.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
url = 'https://mamaearth.in'
key = ['for-babies','beauty','hair','skin','body','gift-packs']
productlinks=[]
for x in key:
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    category = soup.find('a',class_='active').text.strip()
    print(category)
    productlist=soup.find_all('div', class_='Wrapper-sc-1rxgrnt-0 glctKn search-cards')
    for item in productlist:
        items=item.find('div', class_='uniquewhite')
        for link in items.find_all('a',href=True):
            productlinks.append(url+link['href'])
Prod_list=[]
for link in productlinks:
    r=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    pro_name = soup.find('h1',class_='ProductDetailsRevamp__ProdName-sc-1w9tx2u-1 dTITDo').text.strip()
        Prod = {
            'Category':category,
            'Pro_Name':pro_name,
        }
    Prod_list.append(Prod)
df=pd.DataFrame(Prod_list)
df
```

I want a product category alongside of every products I've scraped. Please help me wih my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape the information in just two loops:

```
for x in key:
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    category = soup.find('a',class_='active').text.strip()
    print(category)
    for a in set(soup.select('div.search-cards a')):
        r=requests.get(url+a['href'])
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        data.append({
            'Category':category,
            'Pro_Name':soup.h1.text.strip(),
        })
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://mamaearth.in'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

key = ['for-babies','beauty','hair','skin','body','gift-packs']
data = []
for x in key:
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    category = soup.find('a',class_='active').text.strip()
    print(category)
    for a in set(soup.select('div.search-cards a')):
        r=requests.get(url+a['href'])
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        data.append({
            'Category':category,
            'Pro_Name':soup.h1.text.strip(),
        })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | Category | Pro_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Baby | Nourishing Bathing Bar Soap For Kids - ( Pack of 5, 75g Each) |
| 1 | Baby | Gentle Cleansing Shampoo, 400ml |
| 2 | Baby | Coco Soft Massage Oil with Coconut & Turmeric Oil for Babies - 200 ml |
| 3 | Baby | Nourishing Hair Oil for Babies with Almond and Avocado Oil - 200 ml |
| 4 | Baby | Dusting Powder with Organic Oatmeal and Arrowroot Powder for Babies - 300g |
| 5 | Baby | Original Orange Body Lotion For Kids With Orange & Shea Butter - 400 ml (Pack of 2) |
| 6 | Baby | Foaming Face Wash For Kids With Aloe Vera & Coconut For Gentle Cleansing- 150 ml |
| 7 | Baby | Nourishing Bathing Bar Soap For Kids - ( Pack of 5, 75g Each) |
| 8 | Baby | Major Mango Body Wash For Kids with Mango & Oat Protein - 300 ml (Pack of 2) |

...

---

### EDIT

> What if I also want to add reviews, it is not possible to append dict object. That's why i've updated this code, so you can look into that.

*This would have been predestined [to ask a new question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exactly this focus - But have seen your efforts and therefore gladly show a solution.*

Issue here is not the applying of the `list` of reviews to the `dict` it is caused by naming the variable for json dict the same as our `list` that keeps all the data. So simply rename the variable e.g.:

```
jsonData = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
reviews = jsonData['review']
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://mamaearth.in'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

key = ['for-babies','beauty','hair','skin','body','gift-packs']
data = []

for x in key:
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    category = soup.find('a',class_='active').text.strip()
    print(category)
    for a in set(soup.select('div.search-cards a')):
        r=requests.get(url+a['href'])
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
        D3=[]
        jsonData = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
        reviews = jsonData['review']
        for i in reviews:
            date  = i['datePublished']
            name = i['author']['name']
            content = i['reviewBody']
            D2 = {
                    'Date':date,
                    'Name':name,
                    'Content':content
                }
            D3.append(D2)
        data.append({
            'Category':category,
            'Pro_Name':soup.h1.text.strip(),
            'Review':D3
        })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your logic helps a lot. Also, can you please look into this review part. I want each and every review with date and reviewer name also. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Have made an edit at end of my answer concerning your review question.